# Add dashes after x digits in Edittext

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new on android and want to when i am entering cnic in edittext then after some digit i can put dash on it like:

12221-1338888-3

```
et_cnic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_cnic);
```

How i can achieve this?please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
        edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str =  s.toString();
            if(s.length() == 5 || s.length() == 13){
                str += "-";
                edt.setText(str);
  edt.setSelection(str.length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String content="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText edText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edText);
    edText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(s.length()%4 == 0){
                int starting = content.length()==0?0:content.length();
                content = content+s.subSequence(starting, start)+"-";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how i can add dashes?

Answer (score 0):

```
et_cnic .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           if(String.valueOf(et_cnic.getText()).length>X)//here x is the number of character after which "." will display on edit text

            {
               et_cnic.setText(String.valueOf(et_cnic.getText).substring(0,X)+"*")//x here same the number of charcter which you do not want to replace with"."
             }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Here you have to write your code for adding dashes.

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  int x = 2;
  edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_test);
    edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() == x) {
                edt.setText(s + "-");
                edt.setSelection(s.toString().length() + 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int a = 0; // write this before on create
       @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(s.length()==4 && a == 0){ // this logic will allow you to delete the "-" as well
         number.setText(s+"-");
        number.setSelection(s.length()+1);
        a=1;
    }
    else if(s.length()<4 && a==1){
        a=0;
    }

}
```